# Hibernate hibernate.show_sql is not mapped while read with working upload

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

as i've wrote in title i have specific problem:
upload data is working but reading is giving me that kind of error:

```
TableMetadata:62 - table found: baza.przychodzace INFO 
TableMetadata:63 - columns: [id, wydzial, imie, adres, tekst, data,
miasto, data2, nazwisko, sygnatura] Exception in thread
"AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
przychodzace is not mapped [from przychodzace]
```

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `przychodzace` (   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT,   `IMIE` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `NAZWISKO` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `MIASTO` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `ADRES` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `DATA` date NOT NULL,   `DATA2` date NOT NULL,  
`WYDZIAL` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,  
`SYGNATURA` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, 
`TEKST` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32
COLLATE=utf32_polish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

hibernate.cf:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baza</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <mapping resource="xml/maps/Maps.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Maps.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping package="xml.maps">
        <class name="przychodzace.model.PrzychodzaceModel" table="przychodzace">
            <id name="przychodzaceId" column="ID">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
            <property name="imie" column="IMIE"/>
            <property name="nazwisko" column="NAZWISKO"/>
            <property name="miasto" column="MIASTO"/>
            <property name="adres" column="ADRES"/>
            <property name="data" type="date" column="DATA"/>
            <property name="data2" type="date" column="DATA2"/>
            <property name="wydzial" column="WYDZIAL"/>
            <property name="sygnatura" column="SYGNATURA"/>
            <property name="tekst" column="TEKST"/>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

PrzychodzaceControler.java where everythings happen

public void zapis(PrzychodzaceModel model) {
    model = save(model);
}

public List<PrzychodzaceModel> read() {
    HibernateUtil hib = new HibernateUtil();
    return list();

}

private static List list() {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    List przychodzace = session.createQuery("from przychodzace").list();
    System.out.println(przychodzace.size() + "size");
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return przychodzace;
}

private static PrzychodzaceModel save(PrzychodzaceModel model) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    int id = (Integer) session.save(model);
    model.setPrzychodzaceId(id);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();

    return model;
}

Thanks in advance i have no idea what can be wrong
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
session.createQuery("from przychodzace").list();
```

to

```
session.createQuery("from "+PrzychodzaceModel.class.getSimpleName()).list();
```

You are using `hql` you have to use class names not table names.

Comment: Thank You very much for so quick answer, of course now it is working. I thought that if it is createQuery i need to put there table name. przychodzace.model.PrzychodzaceModel wasn't needed. Merry Xmas and thanks ;)

Comment: The idea of using an ORM it's to abstract about relational model and think in an object way :D

Comment: @user3131128 Please read thru the basics of Hibernate and get the basic understanding first.  Keep on "wild-guessing" is not an effective way to learn